# Indifference Curve Analysis

Tags: utility, covid-19-crisis, real-analysis

I would like to analyse how COVID-19 has impacted the aviation industry by looking at how the demand for airlines + holidays has fallen via an indifference curve analysis. However, I'm not sure where to start
Would the indifference curve shift inwards?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question. Can you give an example of an "indifference curve analysis?"

Answer (score 5):

Indifference curves represent preferences. Preferences are usually assumed to be stable, i.e. they do not change. So no, indifference curves don't shift.